# Black shadow under windows

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers

## Problem

[image: Wrong Shadow]

Almost every window from the core elementary os applications displays a wrong shadow (you can see exactly how *wrong* in the picture above). If I boot using software rendering (boot on secure mode and resume boot normally) the shadow works okay, but as it is software, everything is slowed to an unusable state.

## Affected apps

Applications that are affected by this include (but are not limited to):

- terminal
- geary
- files
- midori
- camera
- music
- maya

Applications that are **not** affected by this include:

- firefox
- gvim
- atom
- audacity
- google chrome

## GTK3?

E.g: it appears to happen only with GTK3 applications and not with GTK2 ones.

## I tried:

I already tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then rebooting, but so far nothing changed.

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1412073), but the result was:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel=2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.3+elementary2+r3~ubuntu0.3.1
E: Version '2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.3+elementary2+r3~ubuntu0.3.1' for 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' was not found
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel`, there shouldn't be a need for a specific version.

Comment: Thanks @LewisGoddard, after a bit of pain it worked. (see my answer)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solution proposed on the comments:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

But it didn't work because I had `xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-utopic` installed, which causes a conflict.

To solve this, I used aptitude to install it (`xserver-xorg-video-intel`) and remove the conflicting packages:

```
sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

But then aptitude removed some core packages, mainly `elementary-desktop`, because they depended upon the `-lts-utopic` version of the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package. To solve this issue, I added the stable elementary ppa with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

and reinstalled the `elementary-desktop` package:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

after a reboot the shadows are working again!

Comment: Uhm, it's great it's working again, but did you _remove_ the stable PPA before all these issues happened?

Comment: In fact, I do not know for sure, but given that apt couldn't find the `elementary-desktop` package before adding the stable PPA, I bet so.

Comment: Well, don't get me wrong, but if there are crucial repositories missing it's small wonder things do not work as intended ... Usually this doesn't simply "happen".